# Does calling AsyncStorage multiple time in a react native app impacts performance?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage, redux-persist

I am building a React Native app which requires calling AsyncStorage multiple times in different components.

For example a particular screen can only be opened in web if the user is logged in, which requires checking the local storage.

Callings AsyncStorage every time doesn’t seem like a good idea and might impact performance as the application grows.

Is implementing redux the best option or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you rely on saving too many records. You can however optimize it by using redux persist or using in-memory cache.

A good read that helped understand optimization and performance of Async: https://medium.com/@Sendbird/extreme-optimization-of-asyncstorage-in-react-native-b2a1e0107b34

Comment: With react persist will I be able to access local storage once when the app loads and then use the values across the component?

Comment: I found a react native library for caching: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cache. It uses AsyncStorage as backend, will this library help me improve performance?

Comment: React-native-cache will improve your perfomance. It is using dictionary to store and retrive: https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-cache/blob/2b3b90e37235d67958cb2a32ede1520f1ab20e70/src/memoryStore.ts#L4